# APC configuration on Ubuntu 10.4. Problem with apc.shm_size, apc.shm_segments and Apache

Tags: php, performance, apache, ubuntu, apc

I've just installed APC to cache my PHP code on my Ubuntu VPS server. Using

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

This worked fine. However, I encounter some problems increasing the chunk of RAM allocated to APC. If I run apc.php it gives me this information about the shared memory.

```
Shared Memory   1 Segment(s) with 30.0 MBytes (mmap memory, pthread mutex locking)
```

Even though I configured

```
apc.shm_segments    3
```

Not setting the default

```
apc.shm_size    30
```

In addition I've got the problem that as soon as I set `apc.shm_size` in `apc.ini` or `php.ini` apache hangs on restart/graceful and wont come up.

My questions:
1. If the memory allocated to APC is `apc.shm_size * apc.shm_segments` why can I only see 90M?
2. Has got anyone had the problem with the hanging Apache on setting of `apc.shm_size`? How would I fix that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the kernel max size for shared memory. On debian-like distribution it's quite low (and ubuntu is a debian-like).
Altering it via sysctl.conf could help you.? Get current value with:

```
sysctl -a  | grep shmmax
```

It's a value in Bytes.

This could explain apache crash when you set a too big number (but you should have something about it in error.log).

Seem for [this response](https://serverfault.com/questions/175948/apc-apc-shm-segments-ignored-apc-shm-size-behaving-weird-in-apache2/179718#179718) that `apc.shm_segments` is not always used by APC. We can see some explanations here: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/apc.configuration.php#94529:

> If you've configured APC to use memory mapped files (with the --enable-mmap option), the shm_segments setting is ignored unless you specify a file mask via the mmap_file_mask setting.
>   Which could be fixed by giving a value to `apc.mmap_file_mask` configuration setting (see link).

But as said in this comment, using several shared segments is certainly worst as using a big one. there is at least two big application which makes heavy use of big shared memory and which always needs an alteration of the kernel settings for that, it's **Varnish** and **PostgreSQL**. Both made the choice of using a big shared segment instead of several.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply! tried to increase the shared memory size via `kernel.shmmax = 134217728` unfortunately this didn't solve my problem. Opened a new question describing the problems more in detail [on serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/291067/apc-configuration-on-ubuntu-10-4-problem-with-apc-shm-size-apc-shm-segments-and)

Answer (score 5):

Seems like i found the problem

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Installed an old version of `APC` on my machine. In that version `apc.shm_size=30M` has to be configuered without the M in the memory size. Thus new versions of APC use `apc.shm_size=30M` old version `apc.shm_size=30`. Once I made the change Apache restarted without a glitch.

Comment: Confirmed with Debian Squeeze. Version of php-apc is the same in lucid, maverick and natty releases of Ubuntu and Debian Squeeze. So users of all those versions should not use M when specifying apc.shm_size.